# Try to push() into an nested array in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to push an object into a nested array in VueJS but I'm getting `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dietMeals' of undefined"`.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a picture of your code. It makes it much easier to decipher. I think you may be incorrectly mutating the data https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods, though I'm not positive.

Comment: @zfrisch Thanks for your answer, maybe i have to do some foreach?